# Getting the position of a JMenuItem from its parent JMenu

Tags: java, swing, indexing, jmenu, jmenuitem

Is it possible to get the position/index of the JMenuItem inside its JMenu?

For instance, I have a JMenu called "Search" and 3 JMenuItems called "Find", "Count" and "Replace", and I have just 1 class manager to manage all the 3 JMenuItems. Hence I use the getSource() method to obtain which of the JMenuItems are clicked, so that I can pass the index of the JMenuItem to the constructor of another class.

My problem is if wanted to add more JMenuItems or to change the order of the JMenuItems, I would have to change the indexes passed to the constructor of the other class.

Thank you!

Comment: *"so that I can pass the index of the JMenuItem to the constructor of another class."* That sounds like a really, *really* fragile approach.

Comment: Each JMenuItem are linked to a certain panel in a JTabbedPane, which is created in the other class. What approach would you adopt?

Comment: @AndrewThompson What I want to do is when the user clicks a JmenuItem of the JMenu, it creates the other class, with the JTabbedPane with the right panel selected

Answer (score 1):

Use [JMenuBar#getMenu()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenuBar.html#getMenu%28int%29) and [JMenu#getMenuComponent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JMenu.html#getMenuComponent%28int%29) methods to get all the JMenu and JMenuItem.

Just iterate all the `JMenuItem` of any `JMenu` and get the index of desired `JMenuItem`.

sample program:

```
JMenuBar menubar1 = getJMenuBar();
for (int i = 0; i < menubar1.getMenuCount(); i++) {
    JMenu menu1 = menubar1.getMenu(i);
    System.out.println("Menu:" + menu1.getText());
    for (int j = 0; j < menu1.getMenuComponentCount(); j++) {
        java.awt.Component comp = menu1.getMenuComponent(j);
        if (comp instanceof JMenuItem) {
            JMenuItem menuItem1 = (JMenuItem) comp;
            System.out.println("MenuItem:" + menuItem1.getText());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Get position/index of JMenuItem from JMenu

---

**Creating a sample nested context menu**

```
JPopupMenu popup = new JPopupMenu();
popup.setName("popup");
JMenu jMenu= new JMenu("menu");
jMenu.setName("menu");
JMenuItem menuItem1 = new JMenuItem("sub1");
jMenu.add(menuItem1);
menuItem1.addActionListener(this);
popup.add(jMenu);
```

**Getting the position/index of JMenuItem from JMenu**

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JMenuItem source = (JMenuItem)(e.getSource());
    try{
        JMenuItem menuItem = (JMenuItem) e.getSource(); 
        JPopupMenu popupMenu = (JPopupMenu) menuItem.getParent(); 
        Component invoker = popupMenu.getInvoker();  
        // Print MenuItem index against the total number of items
        System.out.println(popupMenu.getComponentZOrder(menuItem)
        +"/"+popupMenu.getComponentCount());
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```